# Wordpress get image url (currently using wp_get_attachment_url)

Tags: image, wordpress, url, attachment

Having a little trouble in getting image attachment urls in wordpress. This is my code so far:

```
<?php // find images attached to this post / page.
            global $post;
            $thumb_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'exclude' => $thumb_ID,
                'post_parent' => $post->ID
            );
            $images = get_posts($args);
            ?>

            <?php // Loop through the images and show them

            if($images)
            {
            foreach($images as $image)  
            {

            echo  wp_get_attachment_image_url($image->ID, $size='attached-image');

            }
            }

?>
```

Which returns nothing. If I swap out `wp_get_attachment_image_url($image->ID, $size='attached-image');` for `wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, $size='attached-image');` this works fine, but brings in the image rather than just the url.

Comment: I believe you are looking for `wp_get_attachment_url( $id );` or `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size, $icon );` instead - the function you quoted is not a WP function.

Comment: sorry, I'm fairly new to php. How would I use this above code to loop through all of the images and output the url?

Comment: After reading your comment, and your question again, I realized that there may be something else going on also: Are you wanting all of the ATTACHED images, or are you JUST wanting the featured image? Your code `get_post_thumbnail_id` is only getting the featured image.  Your comment suggests you want to see all images for that post - is that right?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get the URLs of attached images, excluding the featured image. I've managed to achieve this just after posting, using

`$attachment_id = $image->ID; // attachment ID

    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full', false ); // returns an array
     
 
    echo '<img src="'; echo $image_attributes[0]; echo '">';`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code will loop through all image attachments and output the src url.  Note that there are two methods shown, depending on your need.

```
<?php

    global $post;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                    // Method #1: Allows you to define the image size
                    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, "attached-image");
                    if ($src) {echo $src[0];}
                    // Method #2: Would always return the "attached-image" size
                    echo $attachment->guid;
            }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to achieve something similar using wp_get_attachment_src, but in a slightly different way. Your way is cleaner, so thank you!

Comment: the GUID property of an attachment is just that, a GUID -- it should be not treated as a URL to be used anywhere.  That last line 'echo $attachment->guid' can outbut URLs that won't actually be the real URL.  See http://pods.io/2013/07/17/dont-use-the-guid-field-ever-ever-ever/